# How can I monkey-patch the User model provided by Django without having a [Errno 13] Permission Denied when making migrations

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-users

Hey guys I appreciate your help with the following:

I'm monkey-patching the User model through a Model I created called `Contact` (which contains the follower and the person being followed for my follower system feature).

When I make migrations I am getting a `Permission Errno 13` as follows:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_user_following.py'
```

This is my code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rel_from_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='rel_to_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follows {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)


User.add_to_class('following', models.ManyToManyField('self', through=Contact, related_name='followers', symmetrical=False))
```

Comment: are you getting this error during migrate or makemigrations? Did you try sudo?

Comment: @bvmcode I'm getting the error when making migrations.

Comment: try "sudo python manage.py makemigrations", or you might have to chmod a file

Comment: @bvmcode "sudo python manage.py makemigrations" didn't work for me. Do you know how can I use the chmod?

Comment: you can try chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_user_following.py

Comment: @bvmcode I'm getting this: ```jeanca7:~/workspace (master) $ chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_user_following.py
chmod: cannot access ‘/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0010_user_following.py’: No such file or directory```